# Replace parts of echo

Tags: php

I know for a fact that $element2 will contain

```
"<div class='game_description_snippet'>
    // The text I actually only want, which is not within any other tags
</div>"

foreach($html2->find('div.game_description_snippet') as $element2) {
    $lol = $element2;
}
echo "<a target='_blank' title='$element2' href='$url'>$element</a>";
```

How do I remove the div tags and just get the text? Another problem is that there will be a lot of spaces in between the div and the text I want for some reason. How do I remove that?

Is there a way I can just fetch the text from div.game_description_snippet? The text is in between "" if that helps.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: ok, but how do we know you did close this off? `</div>"` or is that irrelevant?

Comment: @Fred-ii- What do you mean (sry)?

Comment: it's probably nothing. I was just curious about the first part of your code `"<div class='game_description_snippet'>
    // The text I actually only want, which is not within any other tags
</div>"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's fetched from another site.. It will contain that div, and a description in between.

Comment: Have you tried using `strip_tags()`? and for spaces `trim()` or a regex would work.

Comment: I just don't know how to apply those to my case @Fred-ii-. I have tried both those, but only ruined the function completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume your're using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) from the code you have.

Documentation shows that you call `->plaintext` if you want the contents without the tags from the element you've selected.

```
foreach($html2->find('div.game_description_snippet') as $element2) {
    $lol = $element2->plaintext;
    echo $lol;
}
```

Using [Advanced HTML DOM Parser](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) instead, but looks like it's drop in a replacement.

Comment: Yes almost, Advanced HTML DOM Parser simply to avoid memory issues. Thanks, that did indeed work!